# Why do spaces affect JavaScript in my html elements?

Tags: javascript, string, syntax, multiline

I am iterating through a JSON object and I am getting the data and created a row in a table. However, when I don't put spaces when I'm appending the rows i.e. I make it just one line, it works.

```
for(var i in data.students)
{    
    table += 
        '<tr><td id="studentName">' + data.students[i].firstname + ' ' + data.students[i].lastname +'</td><td><select class="attendSelect" id="studentSelect'+ data.students[i].lastname +'"><option value="Attended">Attended</option><option value="Excused">Excused</option><option value="Absent">Did not Attend</option></select></td></tr>';
}
```

However, when I try to make it look tidy by indenting and adding spaces. It breaks up. I don't understand!

```
for(var i in data.students)
{    
    table += 
        '<tr>
            <td id="studentName">' + data.students[i].firstname + ' ' + data.students[i].lastname +'</td>
            <td>
                <select class="attendSelect" id="studentSelect'+ data.students[i].lastname +'">
                    <option value="Attended">Attended</option>
                    <option value="Excused">Excused</option>
                    <option value="Absent">Did not Attend</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Note - this is not jQuery this is JavaScript ... (tag added)

Comment: The spaces aren't the problem: it's the new lines that are the problem. And this is general javascript syntax rules: nothing to do with jQuery specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just add line returns inside of strings.  You can do this one of two ways:

```
var mystring = "this" + 
               "is multi" + 
               "line";
```

or

```
var mystring = "this \ 
               is multi \
               line";
```

Note that these two string are not equal.  The first example has no space between the lines.  The 2nd example includes all of that white-space at the beginnings of the lines in the string.

Comment: Hah, thanks.  Looking at the answers it appears someone doesn't even like the mention of using `\\` since all questions with it got downvoted.  While I don't like the use of it either, it is still valid and important to understand how the language works.  Don't see how a downvote is warrented.

Answer (score 3):

Thats the way the just time compiler thinks.

Add a \ at the end of each line within the " string "

Answer (score 1):

That is because [JavaScript injects `;` automatically](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) to the end of your line, which breaks your string because it is unterminated. You can escape line ends with `\` or close the string at line end properly, which is more verbose and less error prone:

```
for(var i in data.students)
{    
    table += '<tr>' +
            '<td id="studentName">' + data.students[i].firstname + ' ' + data.students[i].lastname +'</td>' +
            '<td>'
                '<select class="attendSelect" id="studentSelect' + 
                  data.students[i].lastname +'">' +
                    '<option value="Attended">Attended</option>' +
                    '<option value="Excused">Excused</option>' +
                    '<option value="Absent">Did not Attend</option>' +
                '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `\` for faking multi-line strings in javascript like the others have suggested.

```
str = "this \
       is a multiline \ 
       string";


str = "this \
       is a multiline \
       string";
```

One of these strings has a syntax error that will throw an exception, can you tell which by looking at them?

Using `\` is just asking for a debugging nightmare. Stick to string concatenation (`+`) or interpolation using one of the many templating systems out there such as [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) or even jQuery's templating engine.